# Prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm tring to determine the prime elements in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Consider: Prime ideals are generated by prime elements, and the factor of a ring with a prime ideal is an integral domain (in the commutative case, which this is). So, what are the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and which of them produce factor rings with no zero divisors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $m\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $m$ is a divisor of $n$. And its residue ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.
Hence a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$.
Hence every prime element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $pu$ (mod $n$), where $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$ and $u$ is coprime to $n$.

Comment: Maybe I have this wrong, but I think it is the elements $m$ mod $n$ s.t $\frac{n}{m}$ is a prime divisor of $n$

Comment: @Makoto Kato: This seems to be an example of when prime ideals are maximal in a principal ring (not a PID). Can you give a good example of when prime ideals fail to be maximal in a principal ring? Thanks.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon - $\langle 0 \rangle $ is prime but not maximal, this is the only example in a principal ring as far as I remember

Comment: Ah, silly me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Belgi: You probably mean the elements $\bar m \in \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(m,n)$ in $\mathbb Z$ is prime.

Answer (score 3):

The following is the same as the nice answer by Makoto Kato. It differs by not using the word ideal, and by being *much* longer, and harder to follow.  So what's the point? Perhaps it can serve as a bridge to the more abstract point of view to someone who has seen some elementary number theory.

A prime element in a commutative ring is usually defined to be a non-zero non-unit object $q$ such that if $q$ divides $ab$ then $q$ divides $a$ or $q$ divides $b$.

Think of the elements of the ring as being the numbers $0$ to $n-1$ under addition and multiplication modulo $n$.  Let $q \ne 0$, and let $d=\gcd(q,n)$. For primeness we must have $d \gt 1$, else $q$ is a unit.

If $d$ is an ordinary prime, then $q$ is a prime in our quotient ring. For suppose there is an $x$ such that $qx\equiv ab\pmod{n}$. Since $d$ is an ordinary prime, and $d$ divides $q$ and $n$, it divides $ab$, so it divides one of $a$ and $b$, say $a$. But then $d$ divides $a$ in our quotient ring.

If $d$ is not an ordinary prime, let $d=st$, where $s \gt 1$, $t\gt 1$. Clearly $d$ divides $st$. But it divides neither $s$ nor $t$ in our quotient ring. To show it does not divide $s$, suppose to the contrary that there is an $x$ such that $dx\equiv s\pmod{n}$. Then $d$ divides $s$ in the ordinary sense, which is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\rm\:\ (p,n) = 1\!\!\!\overset{\rm Bezout\!\!}\iff p\:$ is a unit in $\rm\: \Bbb Z/n.\:$ Else $\rm\:\color{#c00}{p\:|\:n}\:$ therefore

$$\rm\: p\:|\: ab\ in\ \Bbb Z/n\:\Rightarrow\: \color{#c00}pq = ab + k\color{#c00}n\ in\ \Bbb Z\:\Rightarrow\:p\:|\:ab\ in\ \Bbb Z\:\Rightarrow\:p\:|\:a\,\ or\,\ p\:|\:b\ in\ \Bbb Z,\ so\ also\ in\ \Bbb Z/n$$

This is aspecial case of a [general correspondence principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54951/242) between prime ideals in a ring R and its quotient rings.